# Не применять групповую политику к локальному администратору

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-10

Локальный компьютер. Хочу разрешить администратору все, а обычных пользователей ограничить

При настройке политики есть настройка применение, где выставлено "применять политику ограниченного использования программ для: всех пользователей. кроме локальных администраторов"

Если погуглить, что это значит:

> Опции политики ограниченного использования программ позволяют запретить выполнение программ большинством пользователей, но в то же время позволить администраторам выполнять любые программы. Например, клиент может иметь общую машину, к которой пользователи подключаются через сервер терминалов. Администратор может захотеть ограничить пользователей выполнением только определенных приложений на этой машине, но при этом позволить членам группы локальных администраторов запускать любые программы. Чтобы сделать это, используйте опцию предотвращения применения политики к локальным администраторам (Skip Administrators).
>
> Для настройки "Применение" указываем, что правила должны действовать для всех пользователей, кроме локальных администраторов. В этом случае администратор сможет запустить любую программу, если запустит ее через меню "Запуск от имени администратора".

Только вот это не работает. Запрет "уровни безопасности - запрещено" применяется ко всем без исключений. И даже "Запуск от имени администратора" из учетки администратора не помогает.

Я читал рекомендации по созданию ярлыков и работе в стиле "отключил политики, накатил обновления, включил", но хочется сделать нормально.